# How to remove search bar

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to remove the search bar completely from my website.  I've had a hard time trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 6):

Rather try this easy way by putting it into local.xml in your theme layout folder

```
<layout>
  <default>
    <reference name="header">
        <remove name="top.search"/>
    </reference>
 </default>
</layout>
```

- Refresh your cache after saving this code.

Answer (score 4):

Place a local.xml file in your template layout (e.g. `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/layout/local.xml`) with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
       <reference name="header">
         <remove name="top.search" />
       </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

If you already have a local.xml file in there, just insert the `<default>` node or the `<remove>` node accordingly.

Comment: Doesn't work. Just tried it on a clean install.

Comment: Please try again, I've been doing it this way for a long time :) make sure you put the local.xml file in the right place and clear your cache

Comment: What version you testing on? I have this setup correctly and the search bar does not get removed

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your theme, but they should all be the same. Open up the template:

`app/design/frontend/[INTERFACE]/[THEME]/template/page/html/header.phtml`

Then, change the following:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
```

to:

```
<?php //echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
```

Clear caches and refresh. The search should disappear.

If you wanted to, you could disable the module completely, but i wouldn't recommend it as it will open up a whole new set of problems regarding dependancies, etc.

Answer (score 0):

just open your "style.css" and find code `#header-search` then add `display: none;` in it or replace with `display: block;` if available

Comment: Perfect, Thank you! I appreciate everyone's help!

Comment: If this is useful for you please accept this as "Answer"

Comment: Don't do following this. If it works, it doesn't mean, that its good solution

Comment: Why not? What will happen if I just edit the css?

Comment: Not happened! your search bar will be hidden as you need, I don't know why others don't accept this method and set negative rating to my answer, I am so sorry for them!!